# How to search in multiple nodes in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a new project using the Firebase realtime database structure. My database looks like that actually:

```
{
  "questions" : {
    "-LEFzp22FBk1PIKjL-Ov" : {
      "description" : "Porque no quiere ",
      "lastModification" : "05/06/2018 19:06:79",
      "tags" : [ "Ingwe", "Dibujo" ],
      "title" : "¿Por qué Ryu no me ayuda? ",
      "userId" : "8LntU2FnnEe05XuSscMNJYGri0g2"
    },
    "-LEG3BE9kBTs5mm6T1QE" : {
      "description" : "Descripción de la pregunta 2 ",
      "lastModification" : "05/06/2018 19:06:66",
      "tags" : [ "Pregunta", "Pregunta2" ],
      "title" : "Pregunta 2",
      "userId" : "8LntU2FnnEe05XuSscMNJYGri0g2"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "8LntU2FnnEe05XuSscMNJYGri0g2" : {
      "id" : "8LntU2FnnEe05XuSscMNJYGri0g2",
      "mail" : "ramon.guardialopez@gmail.com",
      "name" : "ramon guardia",
      "surname" : "",
      "userName" : ""
    }
  }
}
```

For each question, I have It's author's id included.

Thing is to show every question including the user name so I should 'search' every user by userId to retrieve the author.

My Adapter is:

```
package soulapps.codingfamily.ui.community;


import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.chip.Chip;
import android.support.design.chip.ChipGroup;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;
import soulapps.codingfamily.R;
import soulapps.codingfamily.data.model.Question;
import soulapps.codingfamily.data.model.User;

import static soulapps.codingfamily.Constants.DB_USERS_NODE;

public class CommunityAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Question, CommunityAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    // Vars
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    private List<Question> mData;
    private DatabaseReference mPostReference;

    /**
     * Initialize a {@link RecyclerView.Adapter} that listens to a Firebase query. See
     * {@link FirebaseRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
     *
     * @param options
     */
    public CommunityAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Question> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CommunityAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Question model) {
        holder.bind(model, position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.questions_list_item, parent, false);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
            if (onItemClickListener != null) {
                onItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()),
                        viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
        return viewHolder;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // String array
        ArrayList<String> tags;
        // Firebase Question user
        User questionUser;
        // Question title var
        @BindView(R.id.question_list_item_lblQuestionTitle)
        TextView lblQuestionTitle;

        // Question user name
        @BindView(R.id.question_list_item_lblQuestionUserName)
        TextView lblQuestionUserName;

        // Question description
        @BindView(R.id.question_list_item_lblQuestionDescription)
        TextView lblQuestionDescription;

        // Question creation
        @BindView(R.id.question_list_item_lblQuestionCreation)
        TextView lblQuestionCreation;

        // Question chipGroup
        @BindView(R.id.question_list_item_tagChipGroup)
        ChipGroup tagChipGroup;

        // Question user image
        @BindView(R.id.profile_image)
        CircleImageView profileImage;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            //mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        }

        public void bind(Question question, int position) {
            lblQuestionTitle.setText(question.getTitle());
            lblQuestionDescription.setText(question.getDescription());
            lblQuestionCreation.setText(question.getLastModification());
            Picasso.get().load("https://imgur.com/a/aZ2C2WV").into(profileImage);
            // TODO get the username from DB

            // Get the user
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(DB_USERS_NODE).child(question.getUserId())
                    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            // Get user info
                            questionUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

            lblQuestionUserName.setText(questionUser.getName());
            // Filling the array with all the question tags
            tags = question.getTags();
            // Create chips
            for (String tag : tags) {
                // For each tag in the array
                // Creating a new chip
                Chip chip = new Chip(lblQuestionCreation.getContext());
                // Editing the chip data
                chip.setText(tag);
                // Add the chip to the chipGroup
                tagChipGroup.addView(chip);

            }

        }
    }

    /*************************** INTERFACES ***************************/
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, Question question, int position);
    }

    /*************************** INTERFACES ***************************/
}
```

It is actually not working because firebase documentation says that onDataChange event is only called every time the data is changed but I need the data at the start of the app load (no changes will be produced) - I'm not understanding this.

I initialize and call the adapter here:

```
package soulapps.codingfamily.ui.community;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import soulapps.codingfamily.R;
import soulapps.codingfamily.data.QuestionRepository;
import soulapps.codingfamily.data.QuestionRepositoryImpl;
import soulapps.codingfamily.data.model.Question;
import soulapps.codingfamily.ui.main.MainActivityViewModel;

public class CommunityFragment extends Fragment{
    private CommunityAdapter mAdapter;
    private MainActivityViewModel mViewModel;
    private QuestionRepository questionRepository;
    private Query questionQuery;

    @BindView(R.id.fragment_community_lstCommunity)
    RecyclerView lstCommunity;

    public CommunityFragment() {
    }

    public static CommunityFragment newInstance(){
        return new CommunityFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Sets emptyView
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_community, container, false);
        questionRepository = QuestionRepositoryImpl.getInstance(getContext());
        questionQuery = questionRepository.getLast50QuestionsQuery();
        // Bind views
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        // Sets mAdapter
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Question> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Question>()
                        .setQuery(questionQuery, Question.class)
                        .build();

        mAdapter = new CommunityAdapter(options);
        lstCommunity.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        lstCommunity.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        lstCommunity.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        lstCommunity.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(inflater.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mAdapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

How can I retrieve the user data then and include the user data name correctly?

PS. I'm using FirebaseRecylcerAdapter (from FirebaseUi).

Comment: Why not simply store the username with the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this, you need to query your database twice and for that please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference questionsRef = rootRef.child("questions");
Query query = questionsRef.orderByChild("userId").equalsTo(userId);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String title = ds.child("title").getValue(String.class);

            DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid);
            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String userName = dataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", title + " / " + userName);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
questionsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

In which the `userId` is the id of the user for which you are searching for questions. The output will be the title of the question and the user name of your user.

Comment: How does your answer change if there would need to be three lookups and its being loaded to a class?

Comment: Without seeing your requirements, it's hard to answer that, so please post another fresh question, so me and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: please see my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55433036/having-issue-retrieving-correct-information-from-firebase-with-multiple-lookups/55433324?noredirect=1#comment97584860_55433324

Comment: see link above for the actual question